# How to create a data file which can be opened by octave

Tags: octave

I created two files FeaturesX.dat and PriceY.dat using the command:

```
touch FeaturesX.dat
```

and

```
touch PriceY.dat
```

but when I would try to open these files from octave using the command:

```
load FeaturesX.dat
```

This error would pop up:

```
error: load: unable to determine the file format of ...
```

Comment: What kind of data? the `load` command is used to load Octave variables that were previously `save`d from within Octave - to load arbitrary data you'd typically use some kind of delimited text format (CSV, TSV etc.) with `dlmread` or `csvread`. Or low-level C-like `fread` for binary data.

Comment: @steeldriver thank that helped, can't I upvote a comment?

Comment: I have posted a brief answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The octave `load` command is used for loading variables that were saved in a special file format by a previous octave `save` command, ex.:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

>> save('FeaturesX.dat','A')
>>
>> clear all
>> A
error: 'A' undefined near line 1 column 1
>>
>> load('FeaturesX.dat')
>> A
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

>>
```

For loading user-data, you will most often want to use a delimited text file (TSV,CSV etc.) which you can load with the `dlmread` or `csvread` functions.

For binary data files, there is a low-level C-style `fread` function.

You can obtain documentation about all these functions from the built-in octave help system e.g. `help dlmread`.